# Find a sequence on the sphere that converges to the north pole

Tags: real-analysis

I want to find a function $a: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{S}^2$ s.t. $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_{n}=(0, 0, 1)$, if $(x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}) \in \mathbb{S}^2$ then it must happen $x_{1} \to 0$, $x_{2} \to 0$ and $x_{3} \to 1$

As it is a point on the sphere naturally $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$, could the same constant function work, i.e. by taking $x_{1}=x_{2}=0$ and $x_{3}=1$, but I don't think it is the objective of the exercise, any suggestion to build the succession? I would be grateful.

Comment: I would fix $x = 0$ to simplify the equation to just $y^2 + z^2 = 1$ and then $z = \sqrt{1 - y^2}$. From there, to each $n$ I would make $(x_n, y_n, z_n) = \left(0, \frac{1}{n}, \sqrt{1 - \frac{1}{n}^2}\right)$

Comment: @PauloEstêvão True, simple and correct, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if you find any sequence $$(b_n,c_n)\subseteq \{x^2+y^2\leq1\}$$ such that $b_n,c_n\to 0$, then taking $$d_n=\sqrt{1-b_n^2-c_n^2}$$ and $$a_n=(b_n,c_n,d_n)$$ the requirements are satisfied.

For example, you may choose $b_n=c_n=\displaystyle\frac{1}{2n}$ and then $d_n=\sqrt{1-\displaystyle\frac{2}{4n^2}}$, so $$a_n=\left(\displaystyle\frac{1}{2n},\displaystyle\frac{1}{2n},\sqrt{1-\displaystyle\frac{2}{4n^2}}\right)$$
does the trick.